# redemption code of TestFlight can be used for other Apple ID

Tags: ios, swift, testflight

I have the redemption code of TestFlight for "iamgoogler@xyz.com". But i am login with some other email id in TestFlight suppose "iamatStack@xyz.com". Can I use the above redemption code on TestFlight with login id "iAmAtStack@xyz.com" or I need to re-login with "iamgoogler@xyz.com" on TestFlight then only i can redeemed the code. Although I tried to redeem code with another id and it is done successfully. but I am worried, is this have any limitation. I am not able to find any document on it.

Comment: Is the test flight link a public link?

Comment: No internal testing invite.